# Spring data mongodb injection

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, code-injection, spring-annotations

I am creating a web application and it's my first time trying out Spring (using the latest versions). I have viewed countless examples (like everything that is out there), followed tutorials, and I really can't get a small example running. Here are my classes.

The configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "springexample.web.db.repositories")
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {    

@Override
@Bean
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient();
}


@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "springdb";
}


@Override
protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return "springexample.web";
}
```

}

The repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface TerminalRepository extends MongoRepository<Terminal, String> {

}
```

The document class:

```
     @Document(collection = "terminals")
    public class Terminal {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private String address;
        private String phoneNumber;

        public Terminal() {}

        @PersistenceConstructor
        public Terminal(String id, String address, String phoneNumber) {
            this.id = id;
            this.address = address;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

// getters & setters
}
```

From this point I simply tried autowiring (@Autowired) my repository so that I could populate a list. It always returned NullPointerException. I tried injecting it in a @controller annotated class.

Then I tried using a service class then obtained a bean from the application context using the getBean method. (from a class that implements ApplicationContextAware)

I could really use some help on this, been struggling for two days. Thanks.

```
  @Service
    public class RepositoryService {

        @Autowired
        private TerminalRepository terminalRepository;

    //constructor , getter & setter
}

service = applicationContext.getBean(RepositoryService.class);
list = service.getTerminalRepository().findAll();
```